# Component identification: SMD: 120C, F mark

Tags: identification, surface-mount

What is this component? When I search on internet, I get a lot of thermal protection components, but they do not look like this.

I got it as a batch from someone, so I don't know the usage.

The dimensions are 7.5 mm x 5.7mm, it has two legs (one on the other side), which extend to the bottom (thus it must be an SMD component).

[image]

(sorry for the white spots, the camera lens was dirty).

Comment: I think it's a LDO (Low Drop Out) voltage regulator.

Comment: The LF logo belongs to [Littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/surface-mount-fuses/flat-pak-fuses.aspx).

Comment: @joost on what do you base that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there where 3 pins. As Andrew said, it's a littelfuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "LF" means a [Littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/products.aspx) Part. The casing is SMC, meaning it is likely a Transient Voltage Suppressor (TVS). They make an SMC part with the number [SMCJ120CA](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smcj_datasheet.pdf.pdf), which seems like a safe bet as to what this is. The 120C is a bidirectional 120V part.

The job of this part is to limit the voltage on the line it is connected to. In normal operation, it does not conduct, but above a certain threshold, it turns on, effectively clamping the voltage between the terminals like a diode.  In this case, it is meant to connect to a line that is nominally between +/- 120V, starts conducting at +/- 133, and will limit its voltage to +/- 193V. Usually the other terminal is ground, but you can also find them providing differential protection, like between cells of a battery charger.

These are typically found near connectors to prevent electrical nastiness from going inside your board and burning something sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment (accepted and upvoted). I already knew what a TVS is, I plan to use them for my (future) DMX PCB. Too bad I need a different value (for protecting my ICs). But good to know ... maybe I can use them to learn soldering better ;-)

Comment: @Michel Another reason this is a great answer is the explanation of TVS operation. Remember, the site helps future visitors through searches, too.

Comment: @JYelton I never said it is not a good answer (in case it's a great answer, I upvoted/accepted it), so I also think it's a great answer. I just wanted to mention I know what a TVS is (but indeed, it's not relevant for the answer). It was in no means  to say it should not belong to the answer.